# Filling a DataTable with two(or more) joined tables

Tags: c#, mysql, dataadapter

I have two tables that I want to join and use to fill a data table, and I am having an issue with column name collision:

```
-----------    -----------
| Parent  |    | Child   |
-----------    -----------
| ParentID|    | ChildID |
| Name    |    | ParentID|
| Value   |    | Name    |
-----------    | Value   | 
               -----------
```

The SQL statement (MySQL database, in case it's relevant)

```
select p.*, c.* from parent p left join child c on c.ParentID = c.ChildID
```

My adapter code (C#):

```
var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DBConn);
adapter.Fill(table);
```

When I go to read the rows, i expect something like this:

```
var parentName = row["p.Name"];
var childName = row["c.Name"];
```

Instead, it is resulting in this:

```
var parentName = row["Name"];
var childName = row["Name1"];
```

How do i get the column names to use the aliases? I feel like I am missing something obvious, because this seems like it should come up all the time.

Comment: Hey Norm, you should select an answer if we've helped you! :) upvote if you havent yet too.

Comment: Yeah, Rafas answer solves this specific case, but there is a general use case that is doesn't. From below:

It's not a matter of what I "have" to alias, its about removing special cases from the code.  I'd rather alias everything than only some things.

If i can't come up with anything better, his answer asks the question I asked, so I will accept it.

Comment: I think aliasing everything is the right way to go.  If you are generating the sql appending something like `"as " + tablename + "_" + columnname` to each column fixes all your issues and is very clear code.

Comment: Also, @Rafas answer was the first one and so there is no reason he shouldnt get the answer.  Its a great one and I upvoted him.  Ostensibly however, we say the same thing.

Comment: Agreed, I just wish there was a "select p.tablename_*" so i didnt have to explicitly name all the columns. I can use a generator for building the thing that builds the sql, though, which means I don't have to write it all out by hand, at least

Comment: You should look into using an ORM like entity framework or Nhibernate.

Comment: Oh man, I love entity framework, but that's an uphill battle. 3-4 years ago they had some idiot do a bad implementation of EF, and the performance was so bad EF is a bad work around here. I've only been here 4 months, but I'm trying to show that its not EF, but the implementation at fault, but i don't have cache to change out our entire DL just yet. Piece by piece, lol.

Comment: I know that situation friend, keep at it.  Proofs of concept and mini projects help turn the tide.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `name` is a common column name for both tables, you have to give an **alias** in your query to any of them. If you do not provide one, it will provided automatically one for the repeated fields, in that case appending a "1".

In addition, `c.` and `p.` are only internal alias for your query but they not form part of the returning column names.

In your SQL query put the alias (at least one of them)

```
SELECT p.name as parent_name, c.name as child_name, ….
```

And in your C# code use the proper columns

```
var parentName = row["parent_name"];
var childName = row["child_name"];
```

Comment: Is there any way to do a table wide prefix? the actual tables have many columns, and having to individually alias each column is cumbersome.

Comment: You only have to alias those ones that have the same name. In addition, is not good idea to select using `.*` because this cause the database to do an extra query first (internally) to find the column names.

Comment: It's not a matter of what I "have" to alias, its about removing special cases from the code. If I can pass a table wide prefix in to the select (like select p.Parent_*, I know this isn't a thing) then I can make that prefix a variable that can be usable both when writing the sequel and when processing the rows. My model has many tables, and having to write special cases every time a column name collision exists is unattractive, compared to a universal solution. I'd rather alias everything than only some things.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are dealing w/ sql strings its always a good convention to write out all your field names instead of using `*`

In this case your problem is that you have `name` in your query twice, so its auto populating a 1 after it to disambiguate.

Try this instead:

```
select
    p.ParentId,
    p.Name as parent_name,
    p.Value as parent_value
    c.ChildId,
    c.Name as child_name,
    c.Value as child_value
from parent p left join child c on p.ParentID = c.ChildID
```

Your c# code would need to reflect this as well.

```
var parentName = row["parent_name"];
var childName = row["child_name"];
```

Comment: Just a typo issue - you have `c.ParentID = c.ChildID` it should be `p.parentId = c.childId`

Comment: @EvanL Thanks, OP has the column names all capitalized, and mine was lower case. Should be correct now.

Comment: Hmmm... i don't think you can do a join on two columns from the same table.  He has `parent p left join child c on c.parentId = c.childId` and so do you.  It really should be `p.parentId`.  Just nitpicking really, I still +1'd you ;)

Comment: Good eyes?  No... Too much SQL on a day to day basis?  Yes ;)

Answer (score 0):

The aliases in the query are for mysql to know what you mean, if you want unique column names in the output

```
Select p.Name as ParentName, c.Name as ChildName .... etc
```

I certainly wouldn't rely on the Name1 drivel, change your query to `select c.*, p.*` and things will go mental.